# Go Context with http.server

Tags: go

In order to test a server that I am writing, I want to be able to start and stop it in the testing framework.

To do so, I am hoping I can integrate [the context package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) in with the http.Server struct. I want to be able to stop the server when I call the `Done` function and the `ctx.Done()` channel returns something.

What I would love to do would be to just modify [the http.Server.Serve() method](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/net/http/server.go#L1721-L1753), to accept a context.Context and check if it is done, on each iteration of the for loop, like this:

```
func (srv *server) Serve(ctx context.Context, l net.Listener) error {
    defer l.Close()
    var tempDelay time.Duration // how long to sleep on accept failure
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil
        default:
        }
        ... rest is same as original
```

However it seems like if I wanna add that check inside the for loop, I would have to rewrite a lot of the methods, because this method calls other private methods (like http.server.srv), which in turn call other private methods....

I also notice that the for loop will stop when the Accept() method on the listener returns an error.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to get a listener to output an error from it's accept method without accessing its private methods as well.

It seems like I am doing something very stupid and wrong if I have to copy and paste half the http library just to let the server stop using the context package.

I know there are lots of solutions around for supporting context canceling for the ServeHTTP function, but that isn't what I am talking about. I wanna pass a context to the whole server, not just to each incoming request.

Is this just impossible?

Comment: copy whole HTTP package, rename it to MyHTTP, do whatever changes. not stupid at all. Go is just sources and a compiler. libraries or packages in go just set of sources.

Comment: @ThunderCat that's perfect! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. Don't know how I didn't find that package before...

Comment: @JiangYD Yeah I guess that would work, it just doesn't seem very attractive. For one, if they update their http code, then I have to go in and re copy and paste. also in version control, it is a bit confusing to have all this code that I didn't write.

Comment: @saul.shanabrook that is...complete out of my understand to your question.`I wanna pass a context to the whole server, not just to each incoming request. Is this just impossible?`  I mean the the answer you accepted–  Jiang YD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [httptest.Server](http://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server) to create a server that you can start and stop in tests.

If you do use the [http.Server](http://godoc.org/net/http#Server) directly, you can break the Serve loop by closing the [net.Listener](http://godoc.org/net#Listener). When a net.Listener is closed, any blocked Accept operations are unblocked and return errors. The Serve function returns if Accept returns a permanent error.